# Can't get my component button to create a record and ideally get the Id back

Tags: actionfunction

Back again! Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a 'Save' button on my Component that calls an apex class which is supposed to create a record in a DML statement. I am not seeing any errors on the class but fear I am not passing the record ID back correctly and this is stopping the execution. I had something similar a few days ago ..thanks SfdcFox! Suspecting its something similar and have change the qte attribute from list to single object to no success. Im not seeing any execution in the dev console either.

This is my component:

```
<aura:component controller="eveGetOpportunity" implements="force:hasRecrdId />
<aura:attribute name="qte" type="Quote"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
<lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Save" iconName="utility:save" onclick=". {!c.clickGenQ}"/>
</aura:component>
```

This is the Controller:

```
({    clickGenQ: function (cmp,event,helper){

        var action = cmp.get("c.generateQuote");
    action.setParams({
        OppId : cmp.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, (function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set('v.qte', response.getReturnValue());
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.error(errors);
        }
    }));
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},})
```

Here is the Apex Class:

```
public class eveGetOpportunity {
  public static void generateQuote(Id OppId){
    List<Quote> Qte = new List<Quote>();
    for(Opportunity Opp:[SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE id=:OppId]){
      Quote NQ = new Quote();
      NQ.Name = Opp.Name;
      NQ.OpportunityId= Opp.Id;
      Qte.add(NQ);
    }
    insert Qte;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the records when you're done:

```
public class eveGetOpportunity {
  @AuraEnabled public static Quote[] generateQuote(Id OppId){
    List<Quote> Qte = new List<Quote>();
    for(Opportunity Opp:[SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE id=:OppId]){
      Quote NQ = new Quote();
      NQ.Name = Opp.Name;
      NQ.OpportunityId= Opp.Id;
      Qte.add(NQ);
    }
    insert Qte;
    return qte;
  }
}
```

I guess you wrote this to prevent errors if an invalid Id is passed in? Just take the first record from the result, if any:

```
cmp.set('v.qte', response.getReturnValue()[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @sfdcfox !